# Can't create global vue variable ( Vue.prototype.$firebase )

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I submit the form in `login.vue` which will call `submit()`. Then I'm getting below error in the web console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { firebaseConfig } from '@/firebaseConfig';

Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

**login.vue**

```
const authService = {
  methods: {
    submit () {
      this.$firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.login.email, this.login.pass).then(
        (user) =>{
          this.$router.replace('bm')
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to:

```
import 'firebase/auth'
```

after the `firebase/app` import in order to get the Firebase Auth product functionality.

Comment: That's where the Firebase Auth code lives.  Each product has its own imports.